# Can the iCalendar link in Chat be made a little clearer?

Tags: feature-request, chat, events

<strike>It would be superawesome if, when you register for a special event in chat, you could get an [iCalendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) link to register the event in your fav calendar application.</strike>

Superawesome.

Sorry, but "Export?"  Can the link be renamed to something a little more clear, such as "Hey, click here to add this event to your fav calendar application!"

I'm thick.

Comment: YOU AND YOUR D**N QUESTIONS!

Comment: [@JeffAtwood](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3568876d79f0551ec5d77652eb8ae9ef?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)